# Test-first-ruby-master xml builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on test-first-ruby-master, which is located at https://github.com/appacademy/test-first-ruby.

I am working on 13_xml_document.rb. I have to be in honest in that I have absolutely no clue what I am doing with this problem, and am unsure of what the end product is supposed to be doing. I have looked up the solution, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand it. Also, when I use the solution provided, the tests still don't completely pass. It fails at the second test.

If anyone could help me understand what I am trying to achieve with this problem, or could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Below is the tests provided and the solution:

```
# # Topics
#
# * method_missing
# * blocks
# * strings
# * hashes
#
# # Builder
#
# Here we will implement the so-called Builder Pattern: we will make
# an object, XmlDocument, that *builds* an XML file, which can contain
# arbitrary tags.
#
# Stuff you'll learn:
# * method_missing
# * nested closures
# * x"builder pattern"

require "13_xml_document"

describe XmlDocument do
  before do
    @xml = XmlDocument.new
  end

  it "renders an empty tag" do
    expect(@xml.hello).to eq("<hello/>")
  end

  it "renders a tag with attributes" do
    expect(@xml.hello(:name => "dolly")).to eq('<hello name="dolly"/>')
  end

  it "renders a randomly named tag" do
    tag_name = (1..8).map{|i| ("a".."z").to_a[rand(26)]}.join
    expect(@xml.send(tag_name)).to eq("<#{tag_name}/>")
  end

  it "renders block with text inside" do
    expect(@xml.hello { "dolly" }).to eq("<hello>dolly</hello>")
  end

  it "nests one level" do
    expect(@xml.hello { @xml.goodbye }).to eq("<hello><goodbye/></hello>")
  end

  it "nests several levels" do
    xml = XmlDocument.new

    xml_string = xml.hello do
      xml.goodbye do
        xml.come_back do
          xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
    end
  end
end

expect(xml_string).to eq('<hello><goodbye><come_back><ok_fine be="that_way"/></come_back></goodbye></hello>')
      end

      it "indents" do
        @xml = XmlDocument.new(true)

        xml_string = @xml.hello do
          @xml.goodbye do
            @xml.come_back do
              @xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
            end
          end
        end

        expect(xml_string).to eq(
          "<hello>\n" +
          "  <goodbye>\n" +
          "    <come_back>\n" +
          "      <ok_fine be=\"that_way\"/>\n" +
          "    </come_back>\n" +
          "  </goodbye>\n" +
          "</hello>\n"
        )
      end
    end
```

and

```
    class XmlDocument
      def initialize(indent = false)
        @indent = indent
        @indent_level = 0
      end

      def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
        attributes = args[0] || {}
        s = ""
        s << ("  " * @indent_level) if @indent
        s << "<#{method_name}"
        attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
          s << " #{key}='#{value}'"
        end
        if block
          s << ">"
          s << "\n" if @indent
          @indent_level += 1
          s << yield
          @indent_level -= 1
          s << ("  " * @indent_level) if @indent
          s << "</#{method_name}>"
          s << "\n" if @indent

        else
          s << "/>"
          s << "\n" if @indent
        end
        s
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to thank you for posting this question. I have been going through the Test First program as well, and this particular activity stumped me. After reading through the solution code, the answer became clear. I'll try to explain it below!

Because you didn't provide details as to which portion of the answer you didn't understand, I am going to explain as much as possible.

```
  def initialize(indent = false)
    @indent = indent
    @indent_level = 0
  end
```

This provides a set of characteristics to be associated with each new instance of an XmlDocument. That is, when someone runs `XmlDocument.new`, the resulting object will have local variables `@indent` and `@indent_level`. Note that `@indent_level` cannot be modified at runtime because it is not an argument of the initialize method. However, the value `@indent` *can* be modified. It should be set to a boolean value--either true or false.

Also note that it is provided a default value `false` which means that one can create a new XmlDocument object without passing the passing a value for the `indent` argument. Calling `XmlDocument.new` creates an XmlDocument object with `@indent` set to false. Calling `XmlDocument.new(true)` will override the default value with `true`.

You can think of the `@indent` instance variable as a switch. If the switch is set to `false`, the program will not perform indentation. The converse is also true.

Moving on...

```
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
```

This is one of the keys to solving this problem. However, before we get into it, we need to look at the tests.

If you look at the third test, you'll notice that you need to somehow respond to a randomly generated method.

```
 tag_name = (1..8).map{|i| ("a".."z").to_a[rand(26)]}.join
    expect(@xml.send(tag_name)).to eq("<#{tag_name}/>")
```

The first line here generates an 8 character string--`(1..8).map`--and then populates it with a random selection of the letters a-z. The second line uses `tag_name` as a parameter for the `send` method [(documentation)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send). You can think of `send` as performing the work of the period in the following code snippet: `XmlDocument.new`. Here, we are invoking the `new` method on `XmlDocument`. This is equivalent to `XmlDocument.send(:new)`.

So, we send a randomly generated string to an `XmlDocument` object. Let's say this string was `abcdefgh`. This would result in the following: `@xmldocument.abcdefgh`. However, you probably haven't coded a method named `abcedfgh` for the `XmlDocument` class. What are you supposed to do?! Maybe get to work on writing the 208,827,064,576 unique method names that can be constructed from the tag_name generator...

No!!!

Ruby provides us with the `method_missing` method ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing)). Basically, if you send an object a message that it cannot respond to (as is the case when we send a `tag_name` that has not been defined) Ruby responds by invoking the `method_missing` method.

So, if we send `abcdefgh` as a method to our XmlDocument object, Ruby responds by invoking `method_missing`. This *usually* results in the interpreter raising an error. However, you can override this default behavior by rewriting the `method_missing` method for your class in question.

```
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
```

We do that here. Note the arguments that are present here. `method_name` is just the name of the missing method, `*args` are all the arguments we passed to it, and `&block` captures the block we passed to the missing method (if there was one).

Having successfully intercepted the missing method and the important things that were passed with it, we can begin to write some new behavior. I'm going to copy the rest of the code below to emphasize that all of our `method_missing` method is responsible for creating this new behavior.

```
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    attributes = args[0] || {}
    s = ""
    s << ("  " * @indent_level) if @indent
    s << "<#{method_name}"
    attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
      s << " #{key}='#{value}'"
    end
    if block
      s << ">"
      s << "\n" if @indent
      @indent_level += 1
      s << yield
      @indent_level -= 1
      s << ("  " * @indent_level) if @indent
      s << "</#{method_name}>"
      s << "\n" if @indent

    else
      s << "/>"
      s << "\n" if @indent
    end
    s
  end
```

The second line here makes use of the conditional or `||` operator. This line checks to see if our missing method contained any arguments.

If it did, they would have been stored in an array. So, we can extract one of those arguments by referencing the first index of the array with `args[0]`. Note that the arguments the tests pass into the methods are hashes. The hashes are stored in the `args` array. That is, if arguments are present, the value of `args[0]` will be the hash we passed in.

If our missing method did not have any arguments, we set `attributes = {}`--an empty hash. So, in either case, whether we have arguments or not, attributes is set to a hash.

Moving on to the next lines we encounter

```
    s = ""
    s << ("  " * @indent_level) if @indent
    s << "<#{method_name}"
```

The first of these lines creates an empty string `s`. Remember that our goal for this script is to create an XML document. We can model an XML document with a simple string. So, that's why we start with one! For the rest of the lines (and, as you will see, for the rest of the method actually) we proceed to add on to this string using the `<<` method which appends data onto the end of the string. You can see this occurring in the second and third lines.

In the second line, we append blank space (to represent an indentation) onto the string *only if `@indent` is not false!* Then, in the third line, we use string concatenation to embed the method name inside what will eventually become a complete XML tag. For example, if our method name was `hello`, at this point we would have a string `<hello` contained in the variable `s`.

Why are we leaving our XML tag incomplete? Well, remember that we are *building* the tag. There still might be other things to add, so we can't finish yet. In fact, this is what the next lines do.

```
    attributes.each_pair do |key, value|
      s << " #{key}='#{value}'"
    end
```

Here we use the `each_pair` method to iterate over the keys and values contained within our attributes hash (see the documentation). Then, just as we did before, we add those keys and values to our string. For example, if our method was passed with the hash `name: 'stadillac'` as an argument, our string would now read `<hello name='stadillac'`.

Next we need to decide what to do if our method was passed with a block.

```
    if block
      s << ">"
      s << "\n" if @indent
      @indent_level += 1
      s << yield
      @indent_level -= 1
      s << ("  " * @indent_level) if @indent
      s << "</#{method_name}>"
      s << "\n" if @indent
```

Passing in a block means that we are going to be building a string composed of nested XML tags. *(note that this isn't a requirement of* all *blocks. this is just how our program is setup).* So, we need to close off our first tag with `s << ">"`. Then we add a new line if our `@indent` is set to true and we also increase the value of `@indent_level` so that our next tag can be indented properly.

Then we yield to the block and append the return value of this block to our string. In this case, these blocks are just other methods for building XML tags. They do the exact same thing we have done up until this point, and they will also conclude just as we are about to do below.

When we have finished appending the block, we decrease the indentation amount. Then, we append blank space to our string equal to the indentation level if `@indent` is active. We finish off our tag with `s << "</#{method_name}>"` which makes use of string concatenation (just as we did above) to close off our tag. We then add a new line if we are indenting.

And now, the other half of the conditional!

```
    else
      s << "/>"
      s << "\n" if @indent
    end
```

If we did *not* pass in a block, we close off our string with a closing tag `/>`. Remember that if we are executing this conditional, none of the previous if statement will have run. So, in the case of our previous example where we were working with `<hello name='stadillac'`, we just add the closing tag and are left with `<hello name='stadillac'/>`. Add a new line if we are indenting, and we're almost done!

All we have to do next is round the method out by returning our string. You can see this third to final line that contains `s`.

I was hoping to provide more links to documentation, but I do not have enough reputation yet. So I was only able to provide two. I hope this helped!